# Linked list - Insert at end using a rear pointer

Tags: c++, c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm learning about linked list insertions and encountered the following code to insert a node at the end of a linked list (in a rather old and obsolete book for C++ still used I don't know why):

```
void Insert_End(Node * np){
    if (start == NULL){
        start = rear = np;
    }
    else{
        rear -> next = np;
        rear = np;
    }
}
```

My question is shouldn't it be
    np -> next = rear;

PS : np is the new node being inserted at the end, rear points to the last node, start points to the first node.

Comment: No, the next pointer of the (new) last node should remain at NULL.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I figured it out when I posted the question.

Comment: to point the last node?

Comment: This sets the new end-of-list so that if `Insert_End` is called again, the new node goes in the right spot.

Comment: Ohk thanks! (My previous comment got deleted accidentally... If someone from future is here, I asked about the last line's role)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is shouldn't it be np -> next = rear;

No,following pictures may help you understand easily.

When you do `start = rear = np;` for the first time all the 3 nodes may look like below.

```
  ------
  |  np  |
   ------
  ^      ^
  |       |
 ----      ----
|start|   | rear|
 ----      ----
```

for the successive insertion:

when you do         `rear -> next = np;` your list may look like below.

*note: `rear` is still pointing to previous last node of the list and `np1` is pointing to `np2`.*

```
  ------         -----
  |  np1 | ---> | np2 |
   ------        -----
  ^       ^
  |       |
 ----      ----
|start|   | rear|
 ----      ----
```

when you do         `rear = np;` your `rear` gets updated to point current last node.

```
  ------         -----
  |  np1 | ---> | np2 |
   ------        -----
  ^              ^
  |              |
 ----           ----
|start|        | rear|
 ----           ----
```

Comment: Nice ASCII art.  IMHO, linked lists should always be drawn when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is shouldn't it be np -> next = rear;

No, because then no node would be pointing to `np`, and therefore it wouldn't be part of any list (other than the list whose head is `np`). Furthermore, `np` wouldn't be at the rear, since its `next` would be pointing at a node (the node that was `rear` previously). The example is a correct implementation.